description of $T'$ in terms of the dual basis.
Here is the question was reading its solution here Matrix of $T,T'$ and description of $T'$ in terms of the dual basis.:
Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Suppose that $(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ is a basis of $W.$
Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ by requiring $T(v_1) = w_1, T(v_2) = w_2, T(v_3) = 0, T(v_4) = 0.$
$(a)$ Write the matrix of $T$ with respect to the given basis for $V$ and $W.$
$(b)$ Use the notation $\phi_i$ for the elements of the dual basis of $V'$ and the notation $\theta_j$ for elements of the dual basis of $W'.$ What equation defines the dual basis of $V'$?
$(c)$ Give a description of $T'$ in terms of the dual basis of part $(b),$ this one I do not know how to solve, can anyone clarify this to me ,please?
$(d)$ Give the matrix of $T'$ with respect to the dual bases of part $(b).$this one I also do not know how to solve, can anyone clarify this to me ,please?
I want to give solutions to parts (c) in it.
For part $(c),$ the solution is: Since the dual basis of $W'$ is defined as
$$
\theta_j(w_k) =\begin{cases}
   1, & \text{if $j = k$}\\
            0, & \text{if $j \neq k.$}
   \end{cases}
$$
And since $\theta \in W$ is just a linear combination of basis elements of $W$ i.e., $\theta = a_1 \theta_1 + a_2 \theta_2 + a_3 \theta_3$ for some $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in F.$ note that dimension of W is the same as dimension of W'.
And since for $\theta \in W',$ $T'$ is defined as $T'(\theta) = \theta \circ T.$
Then we can say that
$$T'(\theta_j) = \sum_{r=1}^{3} C_{r ,j} \phi_r.$$
Is my answer correct?
